# How to find related entries in SMW by value in subobject field

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Too poor documentation drives me crazy in mediawiki and semantic mediawiki.
What does column subobject in smw_object_ids mean? How can I find something related to record which stores something like `_QUERYgjdfghjsag9u05sdfa` in specified above column?

**EDIT**

And which data smw_proptable_hash supposed to hold? If I unserialize I see:

```
array (
  'smw_di_number' => '3acec8ed7529527ac33713b1668f31c2',
  'smw_di_blob' => 'c201d67c4b8317d31b05d38d796671d2',
  'smw_di_time' => 'eff3878694d4aee1e88eb979bbd30097',
  'smw_di_wikipage' => 'e474079e8c5fab4ec7197d6aaa884032',
  'smw_fpt_ask' => 'e721ae2cb8f49309e10a27467306644c',
  'smw_fpt_inst' => 'c7af3f2c8f2f5276c1284b3855358979',
  'smw_fpt_sobj' => '7fe51e1a5b9c41d770d3dd8b1e1a16fa',
  'smw_fpt_mdat' => 'a400d86be3f69fbb788c4cfcdddaf077',
  'smw_fpt_cdat' => 'd063996afa76760ea758a1ab13deb191',
)
```

But none of them I can't find in specified tables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe you should not perform raw SQL queries to browse semantic data because SMW already has classes and methods for it. Although, they're barely documented, so you'll need to investigate sources to understand how it works and how to properly use it.

You can find some example by looking at sources of [SemanticQueryInterface](https://github.com/vedmaka/SemanticQueryInterface) or since it has support for subobjects you can just use it in your code.

Comment: Was little helpful. But now I have another yet opposite question:

Comment: How hashes are added in mentioned above table? To be precise, I have a page which does not display LastmodifiedBy smwproperty. After debugging I realised that it's not displayed because Lastmodified property is located in smw_di_blob which is not present in list of hashes.

Comment: @Velaro I believe only creator of SMW know all these details, so I think it'd be much easier if you could describe the problem you're trying to solve, maybe there is no need to dig SQL for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to source code

```
[`extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/storage/SQLStore/SMW_SQLStore3_Writers.php:462 - preparePropertyTableUpdates`]
```

hashes gets generated as follows:

```
$newHash = md5( serialize( array_values( $newData[$tableName] ) ) );
```

as instance $newData may be

```
Array
(
    [smw_fpt_cdat] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [o_serialized] => 1/2017/3/22/13/26/37
                    [o_sortkey] => 2457835.0601505
                )

        )

    [smw_fpt_mdat] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [o_serialized] => 1/2017/3/22/13/26/37
                    [o_sortkey] => 2457835.0601505
                )

        )

    [smw_di_wikipage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [p_id] => 754161
                    [o_id] => 2215135
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [p_id] => 754162
                    [o_id] => 2215135
                )

        )

    [smw_di_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [p_id] => 754163
                    [o_serialized] => 1
                    [o_sortkey] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [p_id] => 754164
                    [o_serialized] => 157470
                    [o_sortkey] => 157470
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [s_id] => 2281824
                    [p_id] => 754165
                    [o_serialized] => 638908
                    [o_sortkey] => 638908
                )

        )

)
```

Then, this stuff gets updated as mentioned in 
[extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/storage/SQLStore/SMW_SQLStore3_Writers.php:611 - writePropertyTableRowUpdates]

== To be continued soon ==

Answer (score 0):

Please see the discussion at 
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Architecture_Tradeoffs

The viewd SMW_TRIPLES and SWM_TRIPLES_NS will give you access to the subject, predicate, object and type of the triples stored in SQLStore3.

The way it works shows you how the general structure of the SQLStore3 database is linking items.

now you are specifically asking for the table smw_object_ids

which has the following columns:

```
Field               Type            Null Key    Default Extra
smw_id              int(8) unsigned NO   PRI    (null)  auto_increment
smw_namespace       int(11)         NO          (null)  
smw_title           varbinary(255)  NO   MUL    (null)  
smw_iw              varbinary(32)   NO          (null)  
smw_subobject       varbinary(255)  NO          (null)  
smw_sortkey         varbinary(255)  NO   MUL    (null)  
smw_proptable_hash  mediumblob      YES         (null)
```

to be able to view the content of the varbinaries you might want to use a cast e.g. like

```sql
select smw_id as id, cast(smw_subobject as char) as subobject,cast(smw_title as char) 
as title 
from smw_object_ids
where length(smw_subobject)>0
```

Now you'll see that subobject have an internal hash code that is appended to the page title to make the subobjects identifiable within a page.

Here is an example of page called "HammerUndSichel" which has four subobjects:

```
id      subobject                           title
91147   _0a12ff61e3b10c31478f2ff62b49e68e   HammerUndSichel
91149   _52193085936ccfee4bc197ce37614073   HammerUndSichel
91207   _7fba483328e69e6aeb6dff0fc74447f4   HammerUndSichel
91148   _838fe1bff8f83dbfa40fb3314c47677b   HammerUndSichel
```

For the internal storage the "id" column is used and the subobject column does not come into play yet. The trouble only starts when you would like to do some kind of reverse search. E.g. the subobject with the id 91147 and the subobject _0a12ff61e3b10c31478f2ff62b49e68e you'd like to find out some property value set within that subobject. Within an ask query you do this with hasSubObject in the SQL Store this gets more tricky.

The SMW_TRIPLES_NS view addresses the issue by adding the namespace and subobject information to each subject in the triples. This allows to uniquely identify subobject triples.

For the second part of your question regarding the hash please look at some of the other answers which seem to be more competent on the issue than me.